# couldn't find /var/www/cgi-bin

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I want to setup the webserver in ubuntu and run its python files from another os. But I could not find any cgi-bin directory in /var/www/ directory. I know that, for ubuntu, /usr/lib/cgi-bin is the standard directory but the browser could not find its location. When I search for /localhost/cgi-bin, it is looking for /var/www/cgi-bin instead of /usr/lib/cgi-bin. So In which file do I have to make  the changes and what should be those changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just create a /var/www/cgi-bin directory and put the scripts you want to run in there or even link it to /usr/lib/cgi-bin.  Beware though, this can create security issues since anyone who can access the web server can execute those scripts.

Comment: If I /var/www/cgi-bin directory, the scripts are getting downloaded if I mention its path in url. It is not running the scripts in browser. Only html files are working fine.